# [UPD] Как получить имя пользователя в $_SERVER['auth_user'] ?

Tags: apache, apache-modules, php

Разрабатывается небольшой проектик в интрасети на php. Работает на apache. Нужно знать, какой пользователь AD сделал submit формы. Как сделать, чтоб в переменную $_SERVER['auth_user'] попадало имя залогиненного при этом пользователя?

В общем оба варианта предложенные тут не прокатили... :(
В первом случае т.к сервер работает на линуксе vbscript не катит. 
Второй вариант - обращение к LDAP. Тут тоже получить имя залогиненного пользователя скорее  всего не удастся, т.к. LDAP по идее для этого просто не предназначен. См.комментарии ниже
http://serverfault.com/questions/180918/find-users-currently-logged-in-using-ldap

Вместо этого можно настроить авторизацию apache в AD через LDAP. Тогда в переменную PHP_AUTH_USER попадает имя доменного пользователя. Правда тут тоже есть нюанс. На текущий момент реализовал только непрозрачную basic авторизацию (самый простой вариант), т.е. с вводом логина и пароля. Как будет с прозрачной - пока непонятно...

Comment: а как вы сделали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странное желание :) именно там нужно получить?

Дело в том, что есть `PHP_AUTH_USER`, в которую попадает имя пользователя при *HTTP basic auth*, и есть `AUTH_USER`, в которую может попасть что угодно (стандартом не определено), вплоть до пользователя, от которого запущен веб-сервер, не обязательно имя из AD.

Так что нужно прямо обратиться за именем пользователя по LDAP, например. Или [вот пример](http://phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?p=10972744), как это делают через NetBIOS.

Comment: Так мы уже пробовали :) не прокатило...код брал один к одному (может быть так делать и не стоило).
В принципе без разницы,откуда получать эти данные.. главное, чтоб юзеру не приходилось вводить логин/пароль, но скрипт знал, кто нажал на кнопку...

Comment: Прямо этот код не стоило, там невнятное получение айпишника и самопальный наколеночный запрос в NetBIOS. Я бы через LDAP попробовал.
<br/><br/>
Еще вариант. Если у вас такой прямо интранет, что все сидят под виндой и под эксплорером, то можно попробовать получать имя на клиенте, как-то так:

    var wsn = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var user_name = wsn.UserName;

и потом передавать его скрипту в поле формы.

Comment: Через LDAP полагаю правильней. Хотя интранет у нас именно все под виндой с эксплорером.. Я так понимаю, что нужно теперь научиться обращаться с LDAP в php?

Comment: <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php">Угу.</a>

Comment: А вот вопрос похожий. С решениями:
<a href="http://www.techques.com/question/1-5327104/PHP-LDAP-Get-user-details-of-member-which-is-a-member-of-a-group">Get user details of member which is a member of a group</a>

Comment: Спасибо, уже смотрю. В последнем примере показан пример запроса информации о пользователях некоторой группы в AD, где входными параметрами являются имя группы... а вот интересно в моем случае что будет являться параметром запроса?

Comment: спасибо.. поглядим

Comment: Ответ примите, если согласны.